# What is the best way to flatten XML Hierarchy to CSV?

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xslt

I am having a problem converting a XML file to a flat csv file. 
I cannot seem to find a good way to flatten the xml file.  I have tried many that I see online but I can only find one site that does it for me (http://convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm) This formats it the way i need it, But I need to wrap my process in a SSIS package so using a site will not work.

I am using C# to read the XML file and then doing a transform with XslCompiledTransform

Here is the source file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GTINItemInfoProxy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.xxxxx.com/schemas/GS1">
  <header version="2.0" xmlns="">
    <messageId>00000000000001.US.00000008</messageId>
    <creationDateTime>2019-02-08T11:52:15</creationDateTime>
    <businessUnit>Example</businessUnit>
    <sourceSystem>HCS</sourceSystem>
  </header>
  <GTINItemInfo version="2.0" xmlns="">
    <item>
      <gtin>00000000000001</gtin>
      <informationProviderGLN>0000000000001</informationProviderGLN>
      <internalId>24008</internalId>
      <state>RELEASED</state>
      <lastStateModifiedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</lastStateModifiedDate>
      <internalProductDescription>Example</internalProductDescription>
      <effectiveDate>2018-06-20T14:25:09</effectiveDate>
      <globalAttributes>
        <productType>EA</productType>
        <globalClassificationCategory>
          <code>3213213213</code>
        </globalClassificationCategory>
        <gtinNameList>
          <gtinName lang="en">Example</gtinName>
        </gtinNameList>
        <brandName>Example</brandName>
        <brandOwnerGLN>000010001010</brandOwnerGLN>
        <netContentList>
          <netContent uom="EA">1</netContent>
        </netContentList>
        <totalQuantityOfNextLowerTradeItem>1</totalQuantityOfNextLowerTradeItem>
        <isBaseUnit>Yes</isBaseUnit>
        <isConsumerUnit>Yes</isConsumerUnit>
        <isVariableWeightItem>No</isVariableWeightItem>
      </globalAttributes>
      <targetMarketList>
        <targetMarketAttributes>
          <targetMarket>US</targetMarket>
          <alternateItemIdentificationList>
            <alternateItemIdentification>
              <agency>Example</agency>
              <id>31321</id>
            </alternateItemIdentification>
            <alternateItemIdentification>
              <agency>Example</agency>
              <id>1</id>
            </alternateItemIdentification>
          </alternateItemIdentificationList>
          <shortDescriptionList>
            <shortDescription lang="en">Example</shortDescription>
          </shortDescriptionList>
          <productDescriptionList>
            <productDescription lang="en">Example</productDescription>
          </productDescriptionList>
          <additionalDescriptionList>
            <additionalDescription lang="en">Example</additionalDescription>
          </additionalDescriptionList>
          <isDispatchUnitList>
            <isDispatchUnit>No</isDispatchUnit>
          </isDispatchUnitList>
          <isInvoiceUnitList>
            <isInvoiceUnit>No</isInvoiceUnit>
          </isInvoiceUnitList>
          <isOrderableUnitList>
            <isOrderableUnit>No</isOrderableUnit>
          </isOrderableUnitList>
          <packagingMarkedReturnable>No</packagingMarkedReturnable>
          <minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProductionList>
            <minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProduction>1825</minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProduction>
          </minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProductionList>
          <nonGTINPalletHi>0</nonGTINPalletHi>
          <nonGTINPalletTi>0</nonGTINPalletTi>
          <numberOfItemsPerPallet>0</numberOfItemsPerPallet>
          <hasBatchNumber>Yes</hasBatchNumber>
          <productMarkedRecyclable>No</productMarkedRecyclable>
          <depth uom="in">12</depth>
          <height uom="in">8</height>
          <width uom="in">12</width>
          <grossWeight uom="lb">0.3213</grossWeight>
          <netWeight uom="lb">0.3213</netWeight>
          <totalUnitsPerCase>1</totalUnitsPerCase>
          <preDefinedFlex>
            <alternateClassificationList>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>Example</code>
                <scheme>Example</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>Example</code>
                <scheme>Example</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>Example</code>
                <scheme>Example</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>Example</code>
                <scheme>Example</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>Example</code>
                <scheme>Example</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
            </alternateClassificationList>
            <brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentificationList>
              <brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentification>
                <brandOwnerAdditionalIdType>Example</brandOwnerAdditionalIdType>
                <brandOwnerAdditionalIdValue>Example</brandOwnerAdditionalIdValue>
              </brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentification>
            </brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentificationList>
            <consumerSalesConditionList>
              <consumerSalesCondition>FALSE</consumerSalesCondition>
            </consumerSalesConditionList>
            <countryOfOriginList>
              <countryOfOrigin>US</countryOfOrigin>
            </countryOfOriginList>
            <dataCarrierList>
              <dataCarrierTypeCode>Example</dataCarrierTypeCode>
            </dataCarrierList>
            <donationIdentificationNumberMarked>No</donationIdentificationNumberMarked>
            <doesTradeItemContainLatex>No</doesTradeItemContainLatex>
            <exemptFromFDAPreMarketAuthorization>No</exemptFromFDAPreMarketAuthorization>
            <fDA510KPremarketAuthorization>Example</fDA510KPremarketAuthorization>
            <fDAMedicalDeviceListingList>
              <fDAMedicalDeviceListing>Example</fDAMedicalDeviceListing>
            </fDAMedicalDeviceListingList>
            <gs1TradeItemIdentificationKey>
              <code>Example</code>
              <value>14</value>
            </gs1TradeItemIdentificationKey>
            <isTradeItemManagedByManufactureDate>true</isTradeItemManagedByManufactureDate>
            <manufacturerList>
              <manufacturer>
                <gln>0100000000000</gln>
              </manufacturer>
            </manufacturerList>
            <manufacturerDeclaredReusabilityType>SINGLE_USE</manufacturerDeclaredReusabilityType>
            <mRICompatibilityCode>UNSPECIFIED</mRICompatibilityCode>
            <serialNumberLocationCodeList>
              <serialNumberLocationCode>NOT_MARKED</serialNumberLocationCode>
            </serialNumberLocationCodeList>
            <tradeChannelList>
              <tradeChannel>Example</tradeChannel>
            </tradeChannelList>
            <tradeItemContactInfoList>
              <tradeItemContactInfo>
                <availableTime lang="en">2019-02-08T00:00:00</availableTime>
                <contactInfoGLN>0000000000002</contactInfoGLN>
                <contactType>ABC</contactType>
                <targetMarketCommunicationChannel>
                  <communicationChannelList>
                    <communicationChannel>
                      <communicationChannelCode>TELEPHONE</communicationChannelCode>
                    </communicationChannel>
                  </communicationChannelList>
                </targetMarketCommunicationChannel>
              </tradeItemContactInfo>
            </tradeItemContactInfoList>
            <uDIDDeviceCount>1</uDIDDeviceCount>
          </preDefinedFlex>
        </targetMarketAttributes>
        <targetMarketAttributes>
          <targetMarket>CA</targetMarket>
          <alternateItemIdentificationList>
            <alternateItemIdentification>
              <agency>AB</agency>
              <id>123245</id>
            </alternateItemIdentification>
            <alternateItemIdentification>
              <agency>ABC</agency>
              <id>1</id>
            </alternateItemIdentification>
          </alternateItemIdentificationList>
          <shortDescriptionList>
            <shortDescription lang="en">Something</shortDescription>
          </shortDescriptionList>
          <productDescriptionList>
            <productDescription lang="en">Something</productDescription>
          </productDescriptionList>
          <isDispatchUnitList>
            <isDispatchUnit>No</isDispatchUnit>
          </isDispatchUnitList>
          <isInvoiceUnitList>
            <isInvoiceUnit>No</isInvoiceUnit>
          </isInvoiceUnitList>
          <isOrderableUnitList>
            <isOrderableUnit>No</isOrderableUnit>
          </isOrderableUnitList>
          <packagingMarkedReturnable>No</packagingMarkedReturnable>
          <minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProductionList>
            <minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProduction>1234</minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProduction>
          </minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProductionList>
          <nonGTINPalletHi>0</nonGTINPalletHi>
          <nonGTINPalletTi>0</nonGTINPalletTi>
          <numberOfItemsPerPallet>0</numberOfItemsPerPallet>
          <hasBatchNumber>Yes</hasBatchNumber>
          <productMarkedRecyclable>No</productMarkedRecyclable>
          <depth uom="in">1</depth>
          <height uom="in">1</height>
          <width uom="in">1</width>
          <grossWeight uom="lb">0.3</grossWeight>
          <netWeight uom="lb">0.2</netWeight>
          <totalUnitsPerCase>1</totalUnitsPerCase>
          <unitsPerConsumerUnit>1</unitsPerConsumerUnit>
          <preDefinedFlex>
            <alternateClassificationList>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>1234657</code>
                <scheme>Example</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>M000</code>
                <scheme>Example</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>K000000</code>
                <scheme>Example</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>acb</code>
                <scheme>Example</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
              <alternateClassification>
                <code>12346</code>
                <scheme>XXXX</scheme>
              </alternateClassification>
            </alternateClassificationList>
            <brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentificationList>
              <brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentification>
                <brandOwnerAdditionalIdType>XXXX</brandOwnerAdditionalIdType>
                <brandOwnerAdditionalIdValue>100000000</brandOwnerAdditionalIdValue>
              </brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentification>
            </brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentificationList>
            <canadaSpecificAttributes>
              <operatorDescriptionList>
                <operatorDescription lang="en">"Sample"</operatorDescription>
              </operatorDescriptionList>
            </canadaSpecificAttributes>
            <consumerSalesConditionList>
              <consumerSalesCondition>FALSE</consumerSalesCondition>
            </consumerSalesConditionList>
            <countryOfOriginList>
              <countryOfOrigin>US</countryOfOrigin>
            </countryOfOriginList>
            <dataCarrierList>
              <dataCarrierTypeCode>128</dataCarrierTypeCode>
            </dataCarrierList>
            <donationIdentificationNumberMarked>No</donationIdentificationNumberMarked>
            <doesTradeItemContainLatex>No</doesTradeItemContainLatex>
            <exemptFromFDAPreMarketAuthorization>No</exemptFromFDAPreMarketAuthorization>
            <fDA510KPremarketAuthorization>K000000</fDA510KPremarketAuthorization>
            <fDAMedicalDeviceListingList>
              <fDAMedicalDeviceListing>D000000</fDAMedicalDeviceListing>
            </fDAMedicalDeviceListingList>
            <gs1TradeItemIdentificationKey>
              <code>Code</code>
              <value>14</value>
            </gs1TradeItemIdentificationKey>
            <isTradeItemManagedByManufactureDate>true</isTradeItemManagedByManufactureDate>
            <manufacturerList>
              <manufacturer>
                <gln>0100000000000</gln>
              </manufacturer>
            </manufacturerList>
            <manufacturerDeclaredReusabilityType>SINGLE_USE</manufacturerDeclaredReusabilityType>
            <mRICompatibilityCode>UNSPECIFIED</mRICompatibilityCode>
            <serialNumberLocationCodeList>
              <serialNumberLocationCode>NOT_MARKED</serialNumberLocationCode>
            </serialNumberLocationCodeList>
            <tradeChannelList>
              <tradeChannel>TradeChanngelExample</tradeChannel>
            </tradeChannelList>
            <tradeItemContactInfoList>
              <tradeItemContactInfo>
                <availableTime lang="en">2019-02-08T00:00:00</availableTime>
                <contactInfoGLN>0000000000002</contactInfoGLN>
                <contactType>CYC</contactType>
                <targetMarketCommunicationChannel>
                  <communicationChannelList>
                    <communicationChannel>
                      <communicationChannelCode>TELEPHONE</communicationChannelCode>
                    </communicationChannel>
                  </communicationChannelList>
                </targetMarketCommunicationChannel>
              </tradeItemContactInfo>
            </tradeItemContactInfoList>
            <tradeItemMarketingMessageList>
              <tradeItemMarketingMessage lang="en">"SampleMessage"</tradeItemMarketingMessage>
            </tradeItemMarketingMessageList>
            <uDIDDeviceCount>1</uDIDDeviceCount>
          </preDefinedFlex>
        </targetMarketAttributes>
      </targetMarketList>
    </item>
  </GTINItemInfo>
</GTINItemInfoProxy>
```

I am not tied to using the xslt method but I dont really know of a better way.

```
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();

        XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings();
        xsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;

        transform.Load("XML_Flatten.xslt", xsltSettings, null);

        System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Testing\sourceFile_Flat.csv");
        transform.Transform(@"C:\Testing\sourceFile.XML", 
        @"C:\Testing\sourceFile_Flat.csv");
```

This is an example of what I have tried for the xslt

```
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

      <xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
          <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            "<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>",
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="position()  = last()">
            "<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>"<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the output of the CSV to be flattened.
similar to the result here.
http://convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm

I would love to have the column names match the XML tags.  but thats a bonus.

Here is the format that I would expect.
https://pastebin.com/G7M08dj6

```
targetMarket,alternateItemIdentificationList/alternateItemIdentification/0/agency,alternateItemIdentificationList/alternateItemIdentification/0/id,alternateItemIdentificationList/alternateItemIdentification/1/agency,alternateItemIdentificationList/alternateItemIdentification/1/id,shortDescriptionList/shortDescription/_lang,shortDescriptionList/shortDescription/__text,productDescriptionList/productDescription/_lang,productDescriptionList/productDescription/__text,additionalDescriptionList/additionalDescription/_lang,additionalDescriptionList/additionalDescription/__text,isDispatchUnitList/isDispatchUnit,isInvoiceUnitList/isInvoiceUnit,isOrderableUnitList/isOrderableUnit,packagingMarkedReturnable,minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProductionList/minimumTradeItemLifespanFromProduction,nonGTINPalletHi,nonGTINPalletTi,numberOfItemsPerPallet,hasBatchNumber,productMarkedRecyclable,depth/_uom,depth/__text,height/_uom,height/__text,width/_uom,width/__text,grossWeight/_uom,grossWeight/__text,netWeight/_uom,netWeight/__text,totalUnitsPerCase,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/0/code,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/0/scheme,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/1/code,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/1/scheme,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/2/code,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/2/scheme,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/3/code,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/3/scheme,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/4/code,preDefinedFlex/alternateClassificationList/alternateClassification/4/scheme,preDefinedFlex/brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentificationList/brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentification/brandOwnerAdditionalIdType,preDefinedFlex/brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentificationList/brandOwnerAdditionalTradeItemIdentification/brandOwnerAdditionalIdValue,preDefinedFlex/consumerSalesConditionList/consumerSalesCondition,preDefinedFlex/countryOfOriginList/countryOfOrigin,preDefinedFlex/dataCarrierList/dataCarrierTypeCode,preDefinedFlex/donationIdentificationNumberMarked,preDefinedFlex/doesTradeItemContainLatex,preDefinedFlex/exemptFromFDAPreMarketAuthorization,preDefinedFlex/fDA510KPremarketAuthorization,preDefinedFlex/fDAMedicalDeviceListingList/fDAMedicalDeviceListing,preDefinedFlex/gs1TradeItemIdentificationKey/code,preDefinedFlex/gs1TradeItemIdentificationKey/value,preDefinedFlex/isTradeItemManagedByManufactureDate,preDefinedFlex/manufacturerList/manufacturer/gln,preDefinedFlex/manufacturerDeclaredReusabilityType,preDefinedFlex/mRICompatibilityCode,preDefinedFlex/serialNumberLocationCodeList/serialNumberLocationCode,preDefinedFlex/tradeChannelList/tradeChannel,preDefinedFlex/tradeItemContactInfoList/tradeItemContactInfo/availableTime/_lang,preDefinedFlex/tradeItemContactInfoList/tradeItemContactInfo/availableTime/__text,preDefinedFlex/tradeItemContactInfoList/tradeItemContactInfo/contactInfoGLN,preDefinedFlex/tradeItemContactInfoList/tradeItemContactInfo/contactType,preDefinedFlex/tradeItemContactInfoList/tradeItemContactInfo/targetMarketCommunicationChannel/communicationChannelList/communicationChannel/communicationChannelCode,preDefinedFlex/uDIDDeviceCount,unitsPerConsumerUnit,preDefinedFlex/canadaSpecificAttributes/operatorDescriptionList/operatorDescription/_lang,preDefinedFlex/canadaSpecificAttributes/operatorDescriptionList/operatorDescription/__text,preDefinedFlex/tradeItemMarketingMessageList/tradeItemMarketingMessage/_lang,preDefinedFlex/tradeItemMarketingMessageList/tradeItemMarketingMessage/__text
US,Example,31321,Example,1,en,Example,en,Example,en,Example,No,No,No,No,1825,0,0,0,Yes,No,in,12,in,8,in,12,lb,0.3213,lb,0.3213,1,Example,Example,Example,Example,Example,Example,Example,Example,Example,Example,Example,Example,FALSE,US,Example,No,No,No,Example,Example,Example,14,true,0100000000000,SINGLE_USE,UNSPECIFIED,NOT_MARKED,Example,en,2019-02-08T00:00:00,0000000000002,ABC,TELEPHONE,1,,,,,
CA,AB,123245,ABC,1,en,Something,en,Something,,,No,No,No,No,1234,0,0,0,Yes,No,in,1,in,1,in,1,lb,0.3,lb,0.2,1,1234657,Example,M000,Example,K000000,Example,acb,Example,12346,XXXX,XXXX,100000000,FALSE,US,128,No,No,No,K000000,D000000,Code,14,true,0100000000000,SINGLE_USE,UNSPECIFIED,NOT_MARKED,TradeChanngelExample,en,2019-02-08T00:00:00,0000000000002,CYC,TELEPHONE,1,1,en,"""Sample""",en,"""SampleMessage"""
```

Comment: Please post the exact result you expect to get from converting your example. Minimizing the example would be also a good move. -- P.S. Generic conversion of XML to CSV is a pipe dream.

Comment: The output I am expecting to look like this.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/G7M08dj6

Comment: I am afraid your examples do not clarify the logic that needs to be applied here. It seems you want a row for each `targetMarketAttributes`. But it's not clear what the columns should be. What if one row has 2 `alternateItemIdentification`s but another has 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example you could use as your starting point:

**XS:T 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:gs="http://www.xxxxx.com/schemas/xxx">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/gs:ItemInfoProxy">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>targetMarket,agency1,id1,shortDescription1,lang1, &#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="ItemInfo/item/targetMarketList/targetMarketAttributes">
        <xsl:value-of select="targetMarket" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="alternateItemIdentificationList/alternateItemIdentification[1]/agency" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="alternateItemIdentificationList/alternateItemIdentification[1]/id" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="shortDescriptionList/shortDescription[1]" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="shortDescriptionList/shortDescription[1]/@lang" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
targetMarket,agency1,id1,shortDescription1,lang1, 
US,Example,31321,Example,en
CA,AB,123245,Something,en
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for!  I will take a look at more of this shortly.  I have a follow up to this.  If there is more then one result in one of the tags how would I need to handle that?

Comment: @CoreyM To get the 2nd value of `agency`, for example, use `<xsl:value-of select="alternateItemIdentificationList/alternateItemIdentification[2]/agency" />` - and so on. If you don't know in advance the maximum of how many occurrences each possible field has, you will have to determine that first. Or decide in advance how many you want to get,